# audio not playing in OGG video in Firefox

Tags: video, ogg

I am using the following non-controversial code

```
<video width="711" height="400" poster="so_low.jpg" controls preload>
    <source src="so_low.m4v" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="so_low.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    Sorry, your browser has no video playback capabilities
</video>
```

The video loads in Firefox but there is no sound. The sound icon in the controls has a slash through it. Needless to say, the video with sound plays fine in VLC player on the desktop. The video quality is terrible compared to the MP4, but that is a different story.

Any idea why I don't get any sound?

**Update:** [The actual page](http://punkish.org/So-Low) may be checked in both Safari and FF. Sound works in Safari (and the quality is much better as well), but FF is borked.

Comment: Have you tried set a codec in type source? Like this type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis"

Comment: yes, to no success. You can check out the actual page at http://punkish.org/So-Low in both Safari and FF. Sound works in Safari (and the quality is much better as well), but FF is borked.

Answer (score 2):

Safari is playing the mp4 file. FF is trying to play the ogv. OGV file has flac audio codec, not vorbis. So you need to change your audio encoding to vorbis.

Comment: On the point of video quality, your mp4 is 4 times larger than your ogv. So you are giving 4 times more bits to your mp4, obviously it will look better.

Comment: ok, I tried the following command `ffmpeg -i so_low.m4v -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ar 44100 -r 29.4 so_low.ogv`. Three interesting things. I still get no sound in Firefox on the [actual page with the video tag](http://punkish.org/So-Low) but [loading the file directly in Firefox](http://punkish.org/data/S/SO/SO_/So_Low/so_low.ogv) plays the sound just fine. Also, in spite of using `-r 29.4` my output is still at 15 fps, hence crappy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm fwiw, `ffmpeg -i so_low.m4v -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libtheora -ab 192k -b:v 3514k -r 29.94 -s 960x540  so_low.ogv` is now resulting in sound in FF, but the controller shows the wrong duration (shows much shorter) even though the video keeps playing past the duration shown. Also, the vid quality is still terrible. The fps shows as 12 in spite of me specifying 29.94 as it is in the input file.